On convergence rate of an optimization method with bounded series
I have a question regarding the convergence rate of an optimization method. Specifically, I am interested in a sequence $(x_n)$ generated by an optimization method, which satisfies the following condition with respect to the minimizer $x_\ast$:
Condition:
There exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n - x_\ast| \leq C$.
Given this condition, can we estimate the order of decay of $|x_n - x_\ast|$ with respect to $n$?
Proposition:
Let $(a_n)_n$ be defined as $a_n = |x_n - x_\ast|$. Given that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, does there exist a positive constant $C > 0$ and a natural number $N$ such that $a_n \leq \frac{C}{n}$ for any $n \geq N$?
Questions:

Is this proposition true? If so, please provide a proof.
If the proposition is false, please provide a counterexample.

Additional Information:
I have already understood that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n - x_\ast| = 0$. However, I am struggling to derive the specific rate of convergence.
